# Service Undefined in Angular Component Unit Testing

Tags: angular, unit-testing, karma-jasmine, angular-services

I'm piping an observable into a component with async, but when I include that component in the parent component unit test, it breaks and says the service is undefined. Or more precisely `TypeError: Cannot read property 'subscribe' of undefined`. Could someone with more experience in unit tests please loo at this for me? Thanks!

I'm wondering if it has something to do with my renaming DataService to data, but that doesn't make sense to me.

Here is my spec:

```
describe('SidenavComponent', () => {
  let component: SidenavComponent;
  let fixture: ComponentFixture<SidenavComponent>;

  const dataServiceStub = {
    partners$: Observable.of(['white-label']),
  };

  beforeEach(
    async(() => {
      TestBed.configureTestingModule({
        imports: [SharedModule, MatSidenavModule],
        declarations: [
          SidenavComponent,
          Component({
            template: '',
            selector: 'app-partner-select',
            inputs: ['partners', 'selectedPartner', 'opened'],
            outputs: ['openedChange'],
          })(class PartnerSelectComponent {}),
        ],
        providers: [{ provide: DataService, useValue: dataServiceStub }],
      }).compileComponents();
    }),
  );

  beforeEach(() => {
    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(SidenavComponent);
    console.log('breaks before this', fixture);
    component = fixture.componentInstance;
    fixture.detectChanges();
  });

  it('exists!', () => {
    expect(component).toBeTruthy();
  });
});
```

the relevant javascript in the component class:

```
  constructor(private data: DataService) {}

  get partners$() {
    return this.data.partners$;
  }
```

and the relevant html

```
<app-partner-select
  [partners]="partners$ | async"
  [selectedPartner]="'white-label'"
  [(opened)]="partnerSelectOpen"
></app-partner-select>
```

Comment: Considering that it's done like shown above, and `Cannot read property 'subscribe' of undefined` clearly refers to partners$ and not anything else, I don't see how it's possible, it should work as intended The question doesn't contain http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve . It's not evident that DataService is module provider and not not component provider. Consider providing a way for users to replicate the problem.

Comment: You and I must have different definitions of MCV. Replicating this should be pretty easy. I would do it on Stackblitz but it doesn't look like they have unit test capabilities yet. Parent component has a service, child component consumes an observable from that service with an async pipe. hard to get much simpler than that.

Comment: MCVE means that you provide full code to replicate the problem. You haven't provided full component, only pieces of it. Tests don't need special treatment, see this Angular/Jasmine plunker example http://plnkr.co/edit/3jh4Z6j2I7KPw9uAk9nE?p=preview

Comment: There's nothing else in the component. Anyway I found out the problem is with the child component and the way that declared somehow. It didn't have anything to do with `partners$` like should have been obvious.

Comment: Glad you sorted this out.

Comment: I still haven't figured out the best way to mock the child component. Edit.... just figured it out. It doesn't like when you include outputs for some reason.

Answer (score 0):

I removed outputs from my declared mock component and it works as desired now!